# How to define a listing example environment

Tags: listings

I have read the listing manual document. I would like to use the `lstsample` environment.

It looks like below:

[image: example]

Basically, the output is on the left and the code is placed on the right.

But I don't find where this environment is defined. Is it easy to define a new environment like this?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete package `listings` can be found at CTAN.

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings

The package provides a huge `dtx`-file and a `Makefile`. Inside the dtx-file you can find the definition (see code below).

However if you use the `make all` the compilation produces the file `listings-devel.pdf` where you can find the user documentation and the developer documentation.

If this part is to hard please have a look at the package [`showexpl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showexpl)

```
% \subsection{The \texttt{lstsample} environment}
%
% \begin{environment}{lstsample}
% We store the verbatim part and write the source code also to file.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newbox\lst@samplebox
\lstnewenvironment{lstsample}[3][]
    {\global\let\lst@intname\@empty
     \gdef\lst@sample{#2}%
     \setbox\lst@samplebox=\hbox\bgroup
         \setkeys{lst}{language={},style={},tabsize=4,gobble=5,%
             basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,basewidth=0.51em,point={#1}}
         #3%
         \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname.tmp}}
    {\lst@EndWriteFile\egroup
%    \end{macrocode}
% Now |\lst@samplebox| contains the verbatim part.
% If it's too wide, we use atop and below instead of left and right.
%    \begin{macrocode}
     \ifdim \wd\lst@samplebox>.5\linewidth
         \begin{center}%
             \hbox to\linewidth{\box\lst@samplebox\hss}%
         \end{center}%
         \lst@sampleInput
     \else
         \begin{center}%
         \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}\lst@sampleInput\end{minipage}%
         \qquad
         \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}%
             \hbox to\linewidth{\box\lst@samplebox\hss}%
         \end{minipage}%
         \end{center}%
     \fi}
%    \end{macrocode}
% The new keyword class \keyname{point}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\lst@InstallKeywords{p}{point}{pointstyle}\relax{keywordstyle}{}ld
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{environment}
%
% \begin{environment}{lstxsample}
% Omitting |\lst@EndWriteFile| leaves the file open.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\lstnewenvironment{lstxsample}[1][]
    {\begingroup
         \setkeys{lst}{belowskip=-\medskipamount,language={},style={},%
             tabsize=4,gobble=5,basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,%
             basewidth=0.51em,point={#1}}
         \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname.tmp}}
    {\endgroup
     \endgroup}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{environment}
%
% \begin{macro}{\lst@sampleInput}
% inputs the `left-hand' side.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\lst@sampleInput{%
    \MakePercentComment\catcode`\^^M=10\relax
    \small\lst@sample
    {\setkeys{lst}{SelectCharTable=\lst@ReplaceInput{\^\^I}%
                                  {\lst@ProcessTabulator}}%
     \leavevmode \input{\jobname.tmp}}\MakePercentIgnore}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Marco Daniel in his answer, the `LTXexample` environment from [the `showexpl`  package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) easily allows you to display source code beside the output that that produces.  Here is an example:

[image]

Usually the `LTXexample` environment is used to display the LaTeX source code and the associated output:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstdefinestyle{ListingSample}{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=none,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    morekeywords={begin,end,for,maxint,to,do},
    pos=l,
}


\lstdefinestyle{myLatexStyle}{
    language=TeX,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=none,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    pos=l,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[style=ListingSample]
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
    { do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{LTXexample}


\begin{LTXexample}[style=myLatexStyle]
\newcommand{\Command}[1]{%
   \texttt{\textbackslash#1}%
}%

Inline math is specified within 
a pair of \$ as in $E = mc^2$.

Display math uses \Command{[}
and \Command{]}.
For example: \[ E = mc^2 \]
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rude way to do it so abusing the `minipage` environment:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=trBL]
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
{\setstretch{.9} 
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
{ do nothing }
end;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{verbatim}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

You might as well need the packages to make it work:

```
\usepackage{setspace} %make the \setstrech 
\usepackage{listings} %lstlisting function
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %i work under spanish documents so if it doesnt work put this
\usepackage{float} %this one is important so the text before and after the object whit [H] will work
```